# Highslide: how to make the gallery work directly in the page, not in a popup or modal window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highslide

I'm struggling to set up a highslide gallery to work like the one here: http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/gallery-in-page+caption-above-thumbstrip.html

However, there's a problem that the example on the page above is a **popup** window that is placed **above** everything else in a page.

I want to place the gallery **inside a page**, without any z-indices, absolute positions etc, so that my highslide gallery would look like here: http://www.theinsider.ua/multimedia/543ce96463688/#1

Anyway, right now it seems like there's no way to do this with highslide. Am I mistaken?

Comment: what you tried so far, add HTML ,CSS and JS here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what's known as an "in-page gallery." See the barebones example:

http://highslide.com/examples/gallery-in-page.html

The example from RoadRash's site is also an in-page gallery. It is not a popup that floats above everything else on the page. Here's an example from RoadRash's site that has three in-page galleries on a page of ordinary HTML. There are no popups, and no modal windows:

http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/3galleries-in-page.html

A regular Highslide JS popup looks like this:

http://highslide.com/examples/mini-gallery.html

Comment: Thanks, @MisterNeutron! The in-page example you posted seems to be exactly what I need!
I'll have to try this out now.

Comment: I've tried the code on my page. It **seems** to work, but another problem appears. I've described it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761907/how-do-i-set-highslide-expander-size
You are very welcome to help with that, too.