# How do I make Highslide thumbstrip scrollable?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, highslide

I wonder how to make a highslide thumbstrip scrollable for cases when there are too many thumbnails to fit into it.

I've got a highslide gallery here: http://civicsector.org.ua/multimeda/foto/208-akcya-geroyi-nezalezhnost.html

However, the thumbnails in it get oblated so that all of them fit into the thumbstrip. Instead, I want them to keep the aspect ratio and to make the thumbstrip scrollable, just like here: http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/gallery-in-page+caption-above-thumbstrip.html

It *seems* that my code is identical to what is in the example page, but for some reason the output is different.

Could please anyone help me with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's CSS (bootstrap.css:101) is clonflicting with Highslide, add this to your CSS

```
.highslide-thumbstrip-horizontal img
{
   max-width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works, too, and is probably safer than my solution.

Comment: I've got one more conflict between Highslide and Twitter Bootstrap, which I've described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796710/highslide-in-page-gallery-gets-broken-by-bootstrap-affix
It would be really great if you could help with that too!

Answer (score 0):

Your own CSS is colliding with the Highslide JS CSS. In the bootstrap.css file, lines 101 and following, you have this:

```
img {
   ...
   max-width: 100%;
   ...
}
```

Remove that max-width attribute.