# Highslide in-page gallery gets broken by bootstrap affix

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, highslide

I've got a highslide gallery in my page http://civicsector.org.ua/multimeda/foto/208-akcya-geroyi-nezalezhnost.html

However, the page also contains a *bootstrap affix* at its top, which appears when you scroll down the page a bit.

If you **open the page and wait** (without performing scrolling) until the gallery fully loads, the gallery is placed just **the way it should**.

However, if **after that** you **scroll down** so that the affix gets shown, and **click to view the next image**, the whole **gallery moves up** so that it actually overlays the previous layout block containing the article text.

It seems like upon the bootstrap affix appearance some kind of a gallery 'refresh' should be fired so that highslide recalculates the gallery position. How do I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When affix kicks in, the affixed div is removed from the normal flow of the page which causes the parent div div to collapse.

**Fix:**
Wrap the affixed div in a new div. Give this dix two different `height`, or hide it, based on the break point of the affixed div (the menu) - which seems to be 1199px and 979px.

HTML:

```
<div class="affix-wrapper">
    <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="250" class="your classes here">
        <!-- content of the div -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.affix-wrapper {
    height: 70px;
}
@media (max-width: 1199px){
    .affix-wrapper {
        height: 139px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 979px){
    .affix-wrapper {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, RoadRash! I've tried it and it _basically_ works. However, there's one problem: **the actual height of the affix is dynamic**. If you make the window a bit smaller (say, 1180 pixels width), the logo and the menu break into 2 lines, and the height of the affix changes. What can we do with this?